# change image on click?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a contextual action bar and I want to change the icon when I press on the item. I have this code.

```
@Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item1:

                mode.finish(); 
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }

        }
```

In xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item1"
      android:icon="@drawable/myNormalImage"
      android:title="x"
      android:showAsAction="always|withText" />


</menu>
```

When the user click on item menu_item1 i would to set an other image (pressed image). How can i do?

Comment: If you're running your code on Android 3.0+, the icons in the menu are not shown by design, why you want do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to change it from `@drawable/myNormalImage` to `@drawable/myAbnormalImage`

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item1:
        // change the icon first
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.myAbnormalImage);

        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the on onOptionsItemSelected method

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.todaySched:

              // put your code here to change the icon
              return true;

          default:
              return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item1:
     item.setIcon(your_condition? R.drawable.your_img1 : R.drawable.your_img2);
    return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following ..hope this will help you

```
 @Override

 public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item1:

           getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.xyz);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }

    }
```